# Can't push changes from my terminal to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project and after making the changes I am pushing it to the repo but I get the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://2001asjad.git/': Could not resolve host: 2001asjad.git
```

I have added a new SSH key as well, but still the same is happening.
Why is this happening, can anyone help me out in how to tackle it?
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your remote url is set up incorrectly, you need to run something like

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:2001asjad/<some repo>.git
```

where `<some repo>` should be the name of the repository you are trying to push to.  For example, if your repo is called "my-project"

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:2001asjad/my-project.git
```

Comment: I did that but now I am getting this @dave :
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '13.234.210.38' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Did you add your new ssh key to your ssh agent?  Follow the steps here https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent